# Pushing to an Array within a jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to parse an XML file, and I'm trying to push each element in the XML file to an array using a jQuery .each loop. Strangely, if I alert the value of the array within the loop it comes out as it should, but if I try to alert a value in the array after the loop has finished it results in "undefined".

Is there something strange that happens when you push values to an array within this kind of a loop?


Here is the Javascript:

```
var splashArray = new Array();

// Load the Splash XML file and assign each image within to an array
$.get('splash.xml', function(xml) {
    $('image', xml).each(function (i) {
        splashArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
    });
});

alert(splashArray[1]); // Results in undefined
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>      
    <image src="splash1.jpg" />
    <image src="splash2.jpg" />
    <image src="splash3.jpg" />
    <image src="splash4.jpg" />
    <image src="splash5.jpg" />
    <image src="splash6.png" />
</site>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct variant:

```
var splashArray = new Array();

// Load the Splash XML file and assign each image within to an array
$.get('splash.xml', function(xml) {
        $('image', xml).each(function (i) {
                splashArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
        });
        alert(splashArray[1]);
});
```

In your variant of code alert(splashArray[1]); executes before ajax get xml result, therefore splashArray was empty, when you try to alert element with index 1. Your code works well only for synchronous mode, when thread waits for server response. In Asynchronous mode you should use callback function.

Variant with callback:

```
var splashArray = new Array();

// Load the Splash XML file and assign each image within to an array
$.get('splash.xml', function(xml) {
        $('image', xml).each(function (i) {
                splashArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
        });
        work_with_splash();
});

function work_with_splash () {
    alert(splashArray[1]);
}
```

Or one more pattern (pseudocode):

```
function process(ajax_is_done) {
    if (!ajax_is_done) {
        ajax(function (result) {
            import_result(result);
            process(true);
        })
    }
}
process();
```

Comment: Yes, your code will correctly retrieve an array inside of the $.get block, but why won't it retrieve it outside of the $.get block. Perhaps I wasn't clear. My problem is not getting the alert() to work, it is making the array values retrievable for later code.

Comment: because it's a callback function, and since Ajax is asynchronous the alert in *your* code tries to alert it before it's defined, before the callback function is fired.

Comment: @cmal, you should use callback for this.

Comment: As an aside, what are the advantages of using push() over `splashArray[i] = foo` when working within a loop?

Answer (score 2):

You are alerting before the array is being populated. You need to understand that XHR/Ajax is asynchronous ( as opposed to synchronous ) so the alert will not *always* run after the callback function because it will take a few seconds to do the actual HTTP request to grab the xml, alerting inside the callback ensures that it is populated after the XHR stuff is done.

Works:

```
var splashArray = [];

function fn() {
    alert(splashArray[1]);
}

$.get('splash.xml', function(xml) {
        $('image', xml).each(function (i) {
                splashArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
        });
        fn();
});
```

Doesn't work:

```
var splashArray = [];

$.get('splash.xml', function(xml) {
        $('image', xml).each(function (i) {
                splashArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
        });
        // this will populate the array almost always AFTER the alert below.
});


alert(splashArray[1]); // this will almost ALWAYS alert BEFORE the callback function is done
```

Comment: Actually both methods seemed to work fine, so the dataType bit doesn't really matter. Are you sure that's the correct xml file path? Maybe you need a root relative such as '/xml/splash.xml' ? Try the Firebug net tab to see if you are requesting the right URI.

Comment: This almost works, but you still can't call splashArray outside of the .ajax function, it results in undefined.

Comment: I thought you were "working on a solution" ? And I didn't alert it outside of the callback, I alerted it inside of the callback, therefore it works and I have tested it.

Comment: I tried working the solution, but kept coming to the same conclusion - the question asker specifically wanted to call the alert outside the callback.

Comment: I get it. The following code executes instantly, before the XML has been fully-loaded and parsed. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a standard callback, the other option is to trigger a jQuery event.